# Stop content from covering tab menu when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a menu page using Bootstrap pill tabs with dropdown. I've placed the tabs to the left, and the content to the right. The content will reach quite far down the page so the tabs need to be able to stick to the top of the page. However, now that they do that, the content overflows onto the tabs when I scroll down. See below for my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container large-padding-top">
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="menuSidebar" style="padding-top: 70px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cakes">Cakes</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Drinks
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tea">Tea</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Coffee">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ColdDr">Cold Drinks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Breakfast">Breakfast</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Lunches
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#LightLunch">Light Lunch</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ChildLunch">Children Lunches</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#OtherLunch">Lunches</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="tab-content" style="width: 100%">
            <div id="cakes" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Our Cakes</h3>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Mud cake</td>
                            <td>£2.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="Tea" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Tea here</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="Coffee" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Coffee here</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="ColdDr" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Cold Drinks here</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="Breakfast" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Breakfast here</h3>

            </div>
                <div id="LightLunch" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Light Lunch here</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="ChildLunch" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Kids lunch here</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="OtherLunch" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Other Lunch here</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#menuSidebar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $window = $(window),
        $stickyEl = $('#menuSidebar'),
        elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });
```

And here are some screenshots of my issue:

[image: Normal]
This is the normal one

[image: Broken]
This is the broken one

Apologies for the logo rubbed out but I shouldn't post it on here :-)

Comment: And what if you remove `position: fixed;` of the `#menuSidebar.sticky` ?

Comment: @VincentG Thanks for replying so quick, however I'm afraid it doesn't stick at all without being fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what is the purpose of your js.  Set `ul.nav-pills` to `position: fixed;` and get rid of your js:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/90t0rauq/)**

CSS:

```
.nav-pills {
  position: fixed;
}
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks for your answer, however, this still isn't working...

I'm not sure what is breaking it as I now have the exact same code as your Fiddle...

I've had a look at dev console, and the elements are the same too...

Comment: look  closer in the dev console at all levels of the dom to make sure your styles are not being overriden

Comment: Hi [@ChrisM](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2588953/chris-m), Thank you so much! I found an overriding CSS style in my bootstrap theme, fixed that and it's all sorted now :)